# Efficient summation of multiplicative functions on intervals

Tags: multiplicative-function, computational-number-theory

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a multiplicative function; i.e., $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ if $m, n$ are coprime.  I'm interested in **efficiently** calculating sums of the form $\sum_{k=1}^N f(k)$, where by efficiently I mean in $\tilde{o}(N)$ operations.  (Tildes above $O$ and $o$ indicate that we are ignoring logarithmic factors.)

This does not seem to be possible for all multiplicative functions.  For example, if we let $f(2^k) = 0$ and $f(p^k) = (-1)^{(p-1)/2}$ for $p>2$, then it seems that computing $\sum_{k=1}^N f(k)$ is at least as hard as determining how the primes in $[N/2, N]$ are distributed among the residue classes $\{1, 3\}$ modulo $4$, and I have no reason to think that this is doable in substantially fewer than $\tilde{O}(N)$ operations.  (I'm not sure if this precise example works, but I think that something along these lines should be as hard as exactly counting primes of some form in $[N/2,N]$, and I think that *exactly* counting such primes is hard to do efficiently.)

---

However, efficiently computing these sorts of sums is certainly possible for some multiplicative functions.  For example, it's well-known that if $f(n) = d(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} 1$, so that $f(p^k) = k + 1$, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^N d(k) = 2\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor} \left\lfloor\frac{N}{j}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor^2.$$  This computation can clearly be performed in $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{N})$ operations.

Similarly, if $f(n) = \sigma_1(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} d$, so that $f(p^k) = \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}$, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^N \sigma_1(k) = \sum_{j_1 = 1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor} j_1\left\lfloor\frac{N}{j_1}\right\rfloor + \sum_{j_2 = 1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor} \frac{1}{2}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{j_2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{N}{j_2}\right\rfloor+1\right) - \frac{\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor^2\left(\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor+1\right)}{2},$$ and more complicated expressions exist for all $\sigma_e(n)$ (at least for non-negative integers $e$).  So again we have an algorithm that takes $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{N})$ operations.

(In general I see no reason to expect "generic" algorithms faster than $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{N})$, simply because computing $f(m)$ for certain $m \approx N$ should involve knowing the primes up to at least $\sqrt{N}$.)

---

I have several related questions:

1. What other common multiplicative functions admit efficient algorithms for interval sums?  For example, can we efficiently compute $\sum_{k \le N} \mu(k)$ or $\sum_{k \le N} \phi(k)$?  We have the easy re-write $$\sum_{k \le N} \phi(k) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{g \le N} \mu(g) \left\lfloor\frac{n}{g}\right\rfloor \left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{g}\right\rfloor + 1\right),$$ but it's not clear to me how to speed this up substantially.  (If I haven't screwed up the details, this formula seems to indicate that any efficient algorithm for interval sums of $\mu(n)$ would give an efficient algorithm for interval sums of $\phi(n)$, with the reverse implication also holding provided we continue to ignore log factors.)
2. Suppose I specify an arbitrary multiplicative function $f(n)$ at every prime power $p^k$ by some "formula" $v(p,k)$.  Suppose furthermore that it is easy (i.e., takes $\tilde{O}(1)$ operations) to compute the "naive sum" $$V(N,k) = \sum_{1 \le n \le N} v(n,k), $$ where we don't take into account the factorization properties of $n$ in computing the naive sum.  Is it "automatic" that an efficient algorithm for interval sums of $f(n)$ exists?  What if we restrict $v(p,k)$ to be a polynomial in $k$, $p$, and $p^k$ (or, more boldly, a polynomial in $k, p, p^2, \cdots, p^k$)?

   I have no reason to suspect this is the case, but it seems like there might be some complicated inclusion-exclusion involving $V(n,k)$ terms that I haven't yet figured out which would give an efficient algorithm.  Note that if $v(p,k) = k + 1$ or $v(p,k) = 1 + p^e + \cdots + p^{ke}$ we recover the cases discussed above.
3. If I have an efficient algorithm for interval sums of $f$ and $g$, can I find an efficient algorithm for interval sums of the Dirichlet convolution $f * g$?
4. Can we make rigorous the idea that there is a natural $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{N})$ lower bound for algorithms for interval sums of multiplicative functions?

Comment: Do you count evaluating $f(n)$ for some $n$ as an $O(1)$ operation?

Comment: An even more efficnet example than $f(n)=d(n)$ would be the multiplicative function $f(n)=1$ -- or $f(n)=\begin{cases}1&n=1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Most arithmetic operations on $n \le N$ take at most $\mathrm{poly}(\log N) = \tilde{O}(1)$ bit-operations.  So for the purposes of this question, it's fine if you think that way.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, your example is just $\sigma_{-\infty}(n)$.  But the point is to sum interesting multiplicative functions, and your example does not help me illustrate the seemingly-natural $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{N})$ lower bound.

Comment: Then for the general case, you *must* evaluate $f$ at all prime powers $\le n$ - and then do about the same number of computations with the results. So what we really need is to count the number of prime powers?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, I made this point in the second paragraph, and presumably you and I both know that the number of prime powers is $\tilde{O}(N)$.  But for questions 1 and 2 I am interested in multiplicative functions with very restricted forms.

It is also not true that you **must** evaluate $f$ at all prime powers $\le N$; often you can get away with evaluating at all prime powers up through $N/2$ and cleverly applying certain corrections.  But I am interested in greater speed-ups.

Comment: The nice $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{N})$ methods for $\sigma_k$ come from $\sigma_k=1\ast\operatorname{id}^k$, $\tilde{O}(1)$ algorithms to compute $\sum_{n\leqslant x}n^k$ (particularly quick for $k=0$) and the hyperbola method. This generalises. If you can compute $F(x)=\sum_{n\leqslant x}f(n)$ in $\tilde{O}(x^{\alpha})$ and $G(x)$ in $\tilde{O}(x^{\beta})$, then, assuming computation of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ is $\tilde{O}(1)$, the hyperbola method with a split at $x^{\gamma}$ gives you an $\tilde{O}(x^{\gamma+(1-\gamma)\beta}+x^{1-\gamma+\alpha\gamma})$ algorithm for $f\ast g$ if I didn't miscalculate.

Comment: The best choice for $\gamma$ is then $\frac{1-\beta}{2-\alpha-\beta}$. Thus the answer to 3. is positive, but it's not as efficient as the algorithms for the factors (in general). Re 1., for $\mu$ (and hence via 3 also for $\phi$) there are efficient methods. See e.g. [Deléglise and Rivat](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1047565447) and [here](https://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/de/node/10199).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks - these are really helpful comments!  The reference to Deléglise-Rivat is in particular quite useful; their Lemma 2.1 seems to be a version of the inclusion-exclusion that I was looking for.  If you wanted to delete the comments and put them as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: I think it may be better to wait a day or two to see whether an expert in computational number theory comes around who can provide a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think it's been long enough, if you want to submit an answer.

Comment: Uh. Certainly more than long enough. I'm sorry, I completely forgot about this. I don't know whether I'll have the time to write an answer today, but if not I should be able to do it tomorrow.

Comment: Some external resources to this can be found by searching "partial summation of multiplicative function", such as https://trizenx.blogspot.com/2018/11/partial-sums-of-arithmetical-functions.html or https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/54150 for example